# Convertir tipo de datos proveniente de una entity a un Type. Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, jpa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un JPA entity from table, que maneja variables BigDecimal (Pdvhdr), y necesito convertirlos a PdvhdrType, para asi realizar una consulta.

El problema es que por ejemplo, la variable TipoCambio, tengo que convertirla a un String (como se muestra al principio), para que en "Public PdvhdrType(){}", pueda ser aceptado como String y mostrarse los datos. Hasta ahi todo bien.

El problema viene cuando intento convertir de pdvhdr a pdvhdrtye, usando Transfer Object, en otra clase. Ya que al momento de convertir "TipoCambioS" a BigDecimal, me aparece el mensaje "The method valueOf(long) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (String)".

No se si estoy bien, ya que tengo otro inconveniente, porque no le puedo dar valor a la variable "private BigDecimal TipoCambio;", ya que los datos los tiene que agarrar de la tabla de la base de datos, asi que tendria que encontrar una manera de que los datos de esa variable, se guarden en "private String TipoCambioS = String.valueOf(TipoCambio);"

Answer (score 1):

### Convertir String a BigDecimal

Usando el método [`decimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html).[`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)):

```
public BigDecimal stringToBigDecimal(String strValue) throws ParseException {
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
    decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true); //Necesario para que devuelva un objeto BigDecimal

    return (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(strValue);
}
```

---

> No se si estoy bien, ya que tengo otro inconveniente, porque no le
>   puedo dar valor a la variable "private BigDecimal TipoCambio;", ya que
>   los datos los tiene que agarrar de la tabla de la base de datos, asi
>   que tendria que encontrar una manera de que los datos de esa variable,
>   se guarden en "private String TipoCambioS =
>   String.valueOf(TipoCambio);"

¿No te sirve usando un método público "setter" para acceder a esa variable privada?